# deploy contract writen by fi failed

Tags: tezos-client

contract source code is:

```
struct ToAmount(
  address to,
  mutez num,
);

storage map[nat=>ToAmount] records;

entry withdraw(address to, mutez num){
    transfer(input.to, input.num);
    let ToAmount thisRecord = new ToAmount(input.to, input.num);
    storage.records.push(storage.records.length(), thisRecord);
}
```

deploy command is:

```
 tezos-client originate contract Withdraw transferring 10 from tz1WfxXzNgcsMrQBV6YHChmyQgNVvfo44ihi running 'parameter bytes;storage (map nat (pair address mutez));code{DUP;CDR;NIL operation;PAIR;SWAP;CAR;DUP;PUSH nat 4;PUSH nat 0;SLICE;IF_NONE{PUSH nat 100;FAILWITH}{};DUP;PUSH bytes 0x61167a68;COMPARE;EQ;IF{DROP;DUP;SIZE;PUSH nat 4;SWAP;SUB;DUP;GT;IF{}{PUSH nat 102;FAILWITH};ABS;PUSH nat 4;SLICE;IF_NONE{PUSH nat 101;FAILWITH}{};UNPACK (pair address mutez);IF_NONE{PUSH nat 103;FAILWITH}{};PAIR;NONE (pair address mutez);PAIR;UNIT;DIP{DUP;CDADR};DIIP{DUP;CDAAR;CONTRACT unit;IF_NONE{PUSH string "Invalid contract";FAILWITH}{}};TRANSFER_TOKENS;DIP{DUP;CDDAR};CONS;SWAP;SET_CDDAR;DUP;CDADR;DIP{DUP;CDAAR};SWAP;PAIR;SWAP;SET_CAR;DUP;CDDDR;SIZE;DIP{DUP;CAR;SOME};DIIP{DUP;CDDDR};UPDATE;SWAP;SET_CDDDR;CDDR}{DROP;PUSH nat 400;FAILWITH}}' --init '{}' --burn-cap 1
```

but I got one err:
[image]

Comment: Just as a warning: i am not sure FI is actively maintained any more (the latest commit is 11 months ago on the fi github). I would use either SmartPy or LIGO as actively developped and maintained high level languages for tezos for mainnet deployment.

Comment: some detail information could be saw at github https://github.com/TezTech/fi-compiler/issues/26

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the initial storage you pass to the contract is erroneous. It should be a `map`. The concrete syntax for an empty map is `{}` and not `()`. You can find this information [here](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#type-map).